# Android 6.0 Marshmallow - cannot connect to a bluetooth peripheral when another app is scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-6.0-marshmallow, altbeacon

I have an app that runs a continuous bluetooth le scanning in a background service, with SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER (similar to AltBeacon).

As long as the service is running, I cannot connect to my bluetooth peripherals with different apps such as [nRF Master Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp) and [BLE Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.macdom.ble.blescanner) (very popular ones). When I shut the service down and then stops and starts the Bluetooth on the smartphone, the connection succeeds.

I don't know if these apps use the new Api (BluetoothLeScanner from level 21) or the old one. Anyways, it does not make sense that one app will be able to prevent other apps from connecting to peripherals (unless, of course, the app connects in parallel to the maximal number of peripherals  that the device can support - but this is not the case).

Can anyone explain this? Did it happen to you before? Is this a known bug? Can there be a collision between apps that use the new Api and apps that still use the old Api?

I tested this on both a Nexus 5 and Samsung Galaxy S5 - both with Android 6.0.

*--- Edit ---*

I developed a simple "connection app" with the latest SDK, including:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
```

(in the build.gradle)

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

(in the manifest)

and all the [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) code that is required for Android 6.0.
I am still having the same problem - as long as the other scanning service is running (by a different app!), the "connection app" cannot connect - [BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) is called with status 133 and state STATE_DISCONNECTED.

There are probably things I should fix in the background service of my first app and avoid a continuous scan so other apps could connect to peripherals (I should probably update its SDK too). Do you know if there is a standard way to implement "beacon monitoring" and still avoid these collisions? What does AltBeacon do about it?

*--- Edit ---*

The same problem happens even after updating both apps to SDK 23.1.1.
One "scanning" app prevents all other apps from being able to connect. What's the right way to implement "beacon monitoring"? Scan periodically and hope you don't collide with other apps that try to connect? This is really ugly...

Comment: It could even be a limitation of bluetooth. Scanning for advertisement packets and following a connection at the same time is maybe not possible.

Comment: Have you tried the same on Android 5.0./5.1?

Comment: I didn't try on Android 5. @zapl It would make sense that the OS will prevent an app from scanning and connecting at once. If one app is scanning and another app wants to connect, the OS should block the scanning app with an error or "blindly" by not giving it scan-results. I hope it's just a collision between the old api and the new api, and soon everybody will switch to the new one. I will test it tomorrow by creating a simple app to try connecting with the new api.

Comment: What makes you think everyone will switch to the new api?

Comment: @ifor When developers will notice that their apps cannot connect when other apps are scanning, they will update their app...

Comment: Or they may just tell people not to use apps that hog system scanning.  You have to say you can not use two apps trying to connect to the same hardware already.  And two on different is not recommended due to the bugs many bugs...  First thing is to work out if it is old api and new api clash.  I actually suspect not but wait for your experiment with interest.

Comment: Many apps today try to implement "beacon monitoring" and have to keep a background scanning. SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER was created so the apps won't need to implement internal timers to start and stop the scanning. AltBeacon are doing a good job trying to standardise this (for example, creating a single background-scanning service instead of service per app). Hogging the system scanning is going to be very common among users...

Comment: Having the same problem on Android 6.0.1...